# Cant find variable ScreenResoultion?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

I have followed this documentation to use Screen Orientation API in the application.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation?_gl=1*1tc0gnn*_ga*MTUzNDQzODI1Ny4xNTgyMjg3MTc3*_ga_REH9TJF6KF*MTYyNTIwMzU5Mi41Ny4xLjE2MjUyMDM5OTcuMA..

In android, the application is working fine with Screen Orientation API.
But in ios throwing Can’t find variable ScreenOrientation error. Because of this error, in UI displaying a blank screen. Please refer to the below image.

[image]

```
Version:
“@ionic-native/core”: “5.34.0”,
“@capacitor/core”: “3.0.2”,
“@ionic-native/screen-orientation”: “^5.34.0”,
“cordova-plugin-screen-orientation”:“3.0.2”
```

Help me to solve this error in ios.

I have created same issue in Ionic forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cant-find-variable-screenresoultion/211892

Comment: Share your Code as well.

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/issues/62